# async series, how to use a function with specific bound variables

Tags: javascript, node.js

Let's say I have a table that contains names and I want to use all of that names in a function. 
e.g `var names = ['joe','sam', 'nick'];`
Lets say I have the following function:

```
function doSomething (string1, NAME, string2, callback){
   ....
   console.log(string1," ",NAME," ",string2);
   ...
   callback(null,"ok");
}
```

Assuming it is asynchronous, I will be using the `async.each` function.
Moreover, I want to pass the variables in the function, using bind like this :

```
async.each(names,doSomething.bind(this, "example1", "example2",function(err){
   console.log(err);
});
```

I get the following msgs :

```
example1 example2 joe 
example1 example2 nick
example1 example2 sam
```

What I want is to bind the strings in the 1st and 3rd position and assign the name to the second. Can this be done? And how? 
Am I missing something in the fundamentals of JavaScript here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What I want is to bind the strings in the 1st and 3rd position and assign the name to the second. Can this be done?

Not with `.bind`. It only allows you to bind the first `n` parameters, but not some of the first `n`.

You can simply use another function though:

```
async.each(names, function(name, cb) {
    doSomething("example1", name, "example2", cb);
});
```

and pass the arguments in any order you like.

Answer (score 0):

It may be not the prettiest solution, but you can wrap the doSomething-function and reorder the arguments:

```
function doSomethingReordered(string1, string2, name, cb) {
    doSomething.bind(this)(string1, name, string2, cb);
}
async.each(names,doSomethingReordered.bind(this, "example1", "example2",function(err){
   console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: `doSomething.bind(this)(string1, name, string2, cb);` is better be written as `doSomething.call(this, string1, name, string2, cb);`